# Active: failed (Result: service-start-limit-hit) (systemctl restart ssh did not clear issue)

Tags: 18.04

In my mission to deploy a python project, I have gotten to gunicorn setup.

Checking for gunicorn status file (I just ran this command earlier today and it returned the following):

```
sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket
Failed to dump process list, ignoring: No such file or directory
● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (listening) since Sun 2020-02-16 21:42:10 UTC; 1min 16s ago
   Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.socket
```

I just now went to run this command and the output was different:

```
sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket
● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: service-start-limit-hit) since Sun 2020-02-16 21:45:01 UTC; 28min ago
   Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)

Feb 16 21:42:10 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Listening on gunicorn socket.
Feb 16 21:45:01 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: gunicorn.socket: Failed with result 'service-st
lines 1-7/7 (END)
```

I ran `systemctl restart ssh`, this did not fix the issue.

Anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: It might be a good idea to look at the error message ;) Unfortunately, you only provided a fragment of the error message: `Failed with result 'service-st`. Please check the complete error message. Maybe it already get's you on the right track, or maby somebody here can help you further with it. Without the error message, all we know is "something isn't working", and that can mean just about anything or everything. It's generally a good idea to read and understand the error messages. Suprisingly often, they almost spell out what's wrong, maybe even how you can fix it.